# Handling php soap server exceptions

Tags: php, web-services, soap, error-handling, exception

I have difficulties handling errors and exceptions on my php soap server. Sometimes the errors/exceptions are caught by my error/exception handlers, and sometimes not. It has been driving me crazy, but now I've been able to create a small example that illustrates the issue. Hopefully someone will be able to understand the behavior and give some advice what to do.

Consider the following php file, running a soap server:

```
<?php

set_exception_handler(function(Throwable $Exception) {
   file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/exception.txt', 'Uncaught exception: '.$Exception->getMessage());
});

//throw new Exception('qwer'); // (1) Invokes the exception handler
//throw new Error('asdf'); // (2) Invokes the exception handler

function SoapFunction() {
//   throw new Exception('bar'); // (3) Invokes the exception handler
//   throw new Error('foo'); // (4) Does not invoke the exception handler!
}

$Server = new SoapServer(null, ['uri' => 'MyNamespace']);
$Server->addFunction('SoapFunction');
ob_start();
$Server->handle();
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/response.txt', ob_get_flush());
```

There are four lines throwing exceptions that are commented out.

By sending a request to the soap server, the file `response.txt` will be created with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="MyNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:SoapFunctionResponse><return xsi:nil="true"/></ns1:SoapFunctionResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

By uncommenting the first exception `(1)` and sending a request to the soap server, the file `exception.txt` will be created with the following contents:

```
Uncaught exception: qwer
```

By uncommenting the second exception `(2)` and sending a request to the soap server, the file `exception.txt` will be created with the following contents:

```
Uncaught exception: asdf
```

By uncommenting the third exception `(3)` and sending a request to the soap server, the file `exception.txt` will be created with the following contents:

```
Uncaught exception: bar
```

By uncommenting the fourth exception `(4)` and sending a request to the soap server, the file `exception.txt` will not be created! But the file `response.txt` will be created with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode><faultstring>foo</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The strange part is that the fourth exception never reaches the exception handler. Instead, the exception message is sent as a soap fault to the client. Can anyone understand why? I am using PHP 7.1.11.

For those who would like to try it out, here is a simple php soap client. Just change `http://www.example.com/server.php` so that it points to the soap server php file described above.

```
<?php

$Client = new SoapClient(null, ['uri' => 'MyNamespace', 'location' => 'http://www.example.com/server.php']);
$Client->__soapCall('SoapFunction', []);
```

Comment: I would take a look at using Zend-SOAP as it has better Exception handling

Answer (score 0):

the soap client is already catching the error so it will stops at that point!
It would have to re-throw the error for it to be caught by your handler.